# listbox selectedvalue property not giving me string value of selection

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selectedvalue

I have a listbox with an image using this same method found [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-listbox-answers-to-popular-questions).

It's a listbox with an items template that has an image and textblock. How do I get the listbox's selected value back?

Like so:

```
string x = listbox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

That doesn't give me the text block's value.  Any ideas?

ANSWER:

Here is the answer:

```
 listboxBinding_Master.Detail.SampleData selectedValue = (listboxBinding_Master.Detail.SampleData)listBox1.SelectedItem;
 string x = selectedValue.ListBoxText;
```

Sampledata is the class I used to define the strings, ListBoxText is the name of the TextBlock.

Comment: Have you set the `SelectedValuePath` on the ListBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `ListBox.SelectedValuePath` to the Name of the Member in the Binded class that represents the value you need.
This way you should be able to retrieve the value via `ListBox.SelectedValue`

**Edit (example):**

```
<ListBox x:Name="TestListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValuePath="LastName" MouseDoubleClick="TestListBox_MouseDoubleClick">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width="110" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Age}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
  {
    public MainWindow( )
    {
      InitializeComponent( );
      var persons = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Person>();
      persons.Add( new Person( ) { FirstName = "Walter" , LastName = "Bishop" , Age = 63 } );
      persons.Add( new Person( ) { FirstName = "Peter" , LastName = "Bishop" , Age = 33 } );
      persons.Add( new Person( ) { FirstName = "Olivia" , LastName = "Dunham" , Age = 33 } );
      TestListBox.DataContext = persons;
    }
    private void TestListBox_MouseDoubleClick( object sender , MouseButtonEventArgs e )
    {
      if ( TestListBox.SelectedItem != null )
      {
        MessageBox.Show( (string)TestListBox.SelectedValue );
      }
    }
  }

  public class Person
  {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public int Age { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: can you give me an example of this?

Comment: I added the example. SelectedItem will remain an instance of Person btw.